# Smarty with multiple parallel templates

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, smarty3

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to add two parallel directories as a template for smarty (3).

In short I would like to create a base template and another custom.
If a custom file is not present then smarty should use the base template which is definitely present.

There is already something that will do that?

Of course, this will work even with the import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can specify multiple template directories using `setTemplateDir`.

Example

```
<?php

// setup template directories
$smarty->setTemplateDir(array(
    './templates',            // element: 0, index: 0
    './templates_2',          // element: 1, index: 1
    '10' => 'templates_10',   // element: 2, index: '10'
    'foo' => 'templates_foo', // element: 3, index: 'foo'
));

/*
  assume the template structure
  ./templates/foo.tpl
  ./templates_2/foo.tpl
  ./templates_2/bar.tpl
  ./templates_10/foo.tpl
  ./templates_10/bar.tpl
  ./templates_foo/foo.tpl
*/

// regular access
$smarty->display('file:foo.tpl'); 
// will load ./templates/foo.tpl

// using numeric index
$smarty->display('file:[1]foo.tpl'); 
// will load ./templates_2/foo.tpl

// using numeric string index
$smarty->display('file:[10]foo.tpl'); 
// will load ./templates_10/foo.tpl

// using string index
$smarty->display('file:[foo]foo.tpl'); 
// will load ./templates_foo/foo.tpl

// using "unknown" numeric index (using element number)
$smarty->display('file:[2]foo.tpl'); 
// will load ./templates_10/foo.tpl

?>
```

You can get more info on this from Smarty.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.template.dir.tpl

and here

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.tpl#templates.from.specified.template.dir

Comment: I've tested this a bit further without too much success, hoping a simple hireachy of skins could be archived. In theory activating the (include_path) variable http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.use.include.path.tpl (disabled as of 3.1) should inherit from one to the other if one file fails. It hasn't worked for us. There is also a function that smarty calls for every failed template that might be worth considering for a patch to change priority or index of template dir array.